# Cpanel setting up cakephp 2.6.3

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have been tasked to migrate an old project running on aws to vps based cpanel, I have done the following:

- setup to cpanel to accept (only) php 5.6 & it's extensions, also setup exported db & it's credentials to required file.
- the path to the project is setup directly on the `public_html/` folder
- the .htaccess file has been configured following :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

which i took from the cakephp installation documentation & added some - [Link](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/installation.html)

The original project htaccess was a bit different however :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    
    php_value max_input_vars 100000

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]

</IfModule>
```

& removing the htaccess or not using it at all in both projects produces same error

```
Warning (2): scandir(../View/Ipac): failed to open dir: No such file or directory [APP/Config/routes.php, line 32]
Warning (2): scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory [APP/Config/routes.php, line 32]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Config/routes.php, line 32]
```

I have tried to use the same htaccess in the new migration along with every other rule which 'seems' okay to me but it shows me internal server error. Now I am stuck here

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
> contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform
> them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
> just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Does anyone know how can I fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "the path to the project is setup directly on the `public_html/` folder" means? Show a little bit of the folder structure that you have set up there?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out that after 2 days of losing my mind on this, the issue was due to the htaccess set incorrectly in the `app/webroot` (which I missed) & also it's index file had a file permission of `775`, which cpanel doesn't allow to be viewed publicly, setting those correctly booted the project up perfectly.